# Running Counts on Multiple Columns with One SQL Query

Tags: sql, count

I'm looking to run a count SQL query on multiple columns at once. 83 of them. For each, I'd simply like to figure out how many instances there are in which the value = 1.

ex.

select count(*) from [filename.filename]
where [Column001] = 1

select count(*) from [filename.filename]
where [Column002] = 1

All data in each column is marked with wither a 0 or a 1.

Instead of writing 83 small queries, is there a way for me to write it all in one query and have them all display as a table with the results?

Comment: show a sample  of data and the expected result  please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Column_1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) N_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Column_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) N_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Column_3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) N_3,
       .....
       SUM(CASE WHEN Column_83 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) N_83
FROM YourTable;
```